# MySQL data migration using .frm .ibd files

Tags: php, mysql, backup, dump

I lost my database backup I could only copy `.frm` and `.ibd` files on time. It was kind of raw table named `raw_blogs` in `test` database now i copied these files into the following directory under new installation of wamp server:

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\test
```

In php my admin i cannot access `raw_blogs` it won't even appear there I restarted all server still no good. Previously i've done it and worked correctly what am I missing now?

Comment: mysql doesn't magically pick up on a db just because you threw some files into its data directory. there's a whole bunch of metadata in other internal Mysql DB's that you don't have. Your best bet is to first CREATE a db on your new server with the same name, recreate all of the tables in it, then overwrite the relevant files with what the "real" copies.

Comment: it has done it in previous version i don't remember which one but it certainly did @MarcB

Comment: @MarcB Logically you are right though, let me try your way...

Comment: @MarcB gives this error `#1146 - Table 'test.raw_blogs' doesn't exist`

Comment: Google "connecting orphaned ibd"